# Dynamically change the value of custom label in a tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, label, cell

I am using a custom label in the tableview cell that I am using. I need to dynamically increase and decrease the height of the tableview cells(label) depending on certain parameters. How can I do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Best way is probably to create a UITableViewCell subclass. Will leave code as an exercise for you.

Comment: try this link:<p>
[UItableviewcell Dynamic Height](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

Answer (score 1):

Implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

method and return the variable height for each row.

Comment: I agree that this is the correct way to go about when you are using the cell's text property to display text. But I have added a label in the cell to display my text. I just want to know, whether this would be the right way to do. Thanks